# how to return all store when filter in react js and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

i have an issue trying to create a "typehead" funcitonality in my app, i have an "input" that listen to onChange, and that onChange is calling to a Redux reducer that search for a tag in hole store, i need to retrive all matches with my search, over here everything is ok, but when i delete my search, my hole store is equals to my filtered results, and i want that when my search is empty it returns hole my store. (gif and code)

[image]

```
case 'SEARCH_BY_TAG':
            let tag = action.tag
            let filtered = state.slice(0)
            if(tag != ""){

                const copied = state.filter(item => {
                        return item.tags.find(obj => {
                            if(obj.name.indexOf(tag) > -1){
                                return true
                            }
                        })
                })

                return filtered = copied.filter(Boolean)

            }else{
                return filtered
            }

 break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should refactor your state to change it from this:

```
[ item1, item2, item3, ... ]
```

to this:

```
{
  query: '',
  options: [ item1, item2, item3, ... ]
}
```

This way you can do what @Raspo said in his answer - do the filtering of the options in your render function.

Currently when you change the text in the search field, you are dispatching this action:

{
      type: 'SEARCH_BY_TAG',
      tag: 'new query'
   }

I think you should change the action name, and the reducer code, to look more like this:

```
// note this is almost exactly the same as the old action
{
  type: 'CHANGE_AUTOCOMPLETE_QUERY',
  query: 'new query'
}
```

and the reducer could then change to this:

```
case CHANGE_AUTOCOMPLETE_QUERY:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    query: action.query
  })
```

Note that in the reducer case I just wrote, the `options` part of the state isn't changed at all. It remains constant.

Now let's assume your current render function looks something like this:

```
const options = reduxState // not sure exactly how you get the state but whatever
return (
  <div>
    {options.map(option => {
      <Option option={option} />
    })}
  </div>
)
```

This code relies on getting the state as an array. You could change it in the new setup to do this:

```
const query = reduxState.query
const options = reduxState.options.filter(item => {
  return item.tags.find(obj => {
    if(obj.name.indexOf(query) > -1){
      return true
    }
  })
})
return (
  <div>
    {options.map(option => {
      <Option option={option} />
    })}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of filtering things out inside your reducer, do it directly on `render()`, there is nothing wrong with that.

You can still use the `SEARCH_BY_TAG` action to keep track of the search keyword and use it to apply the filter when rendering your list.